# Embed asp page without iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I want to embed an .asp page on an html page.  I cannot use an iframe.  I tried:

```
<object width="100%" height="1500" type="text/html" data="url.asp">
alt : <a href="url.asp">url</a>
</object>"
```

works great in ff but not ie7.  Any ideas? Is it possible to use the object tag to embed .asp pages for IE or does it only work in ff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it in the past using Javascript and XMLHttp. It can get a bit hacky depending on the circumstances. In particular, you have to watch out for the inner page failing and how it affects/downgrades the outer one (hopefully you can keep it downgrading elegantly).

Search for XMLHttp (or check [this great tutorial](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html)) and request the "child" page from the outer one, rendering the HTML you need. Preferably you can get just the specific data you need and process it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to fake it using javascript. You could either use AJAX to load the page, then insert the HTML, or load "url.asp" in a hidden iframe and copy the HTML from there.

One downside (or maybe this is what you want) is that the pages aren't completely independent, so CSS rules from the outer page will affect the embedded page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching around and testing I don't think it is possible.  It looks to me like IE does not allow the object tag access to a resource that is not on the same domain as the parent.  It would have worked for me if the content I was trying to pull in was on same domain but it wasn't.  If anyone could confirm my interpretation of this it would be appreciated.